# How to test firebase methods correctly?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, jasmine, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase and need to test services containing firebase methods. I don't find any helpful resources on the web.
Can someone please add some *example test cases for firebase*.
Here is an example of a service method I need to test:

```
createRootCollectionDocument$(collection: string, data: any): Observable<firebase.firestore.DocumentReference> {
    const dataCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any> = this._firebase.collection(collection);
    return Observable.from(
      dataCollection.add({ ...data }).catch((err: firebase.firestore.FirestoreError) => {
        throw err.message;
      })
    );
  }
```

**For instance:**

- If I want to test that the firebase *collection.add* method has been called
- If unsuccessful, throws the message string

This looks like a similar issue: [Need some guidance on how to test AngularFireAuth properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027740/need-some-guidance-on-how-to-test-angularfireauth-properly)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't this _throw err.message_ throwing the message string?

Comment: Yes, my problem is to test methods containing firebase methods. I can only test specific firebase methods which gets handled in the test itself, so the rest of the code doesn't execute. That's why I'm asking for a test case testing that the firebase method has been called and the code continues to execute etc..

Comment: use mocks. In your test inject a mocked firebase service instead of the actual one.

Comment: Thanks toskv. Can you perhaps provide a link or example please?

Comment: the angular guide on testing has examples on that, a good example is in the service tests. https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests